# Your bundle requires gems that depend on each other, creating an infinite loop. Please remove gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I'm upgrading some gems. When I calll `bundle` I have this:

```
Your bundle requires gems that depend on each other, creating an 
infinite loop. Please remove gem 'abc' and try again.
```

I've removed but this error persists.

Comment: Tell us what gems you're dealing with and the *exact* steps you're using in an attempt to resolve your issue?

Comment: In my case I made an error in a git merge. So bundle update solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to remove your Gemfile.lock, then run `bundle update`.

Why this would work? Sometimes you are forcing old versions of gems to be loaded, and you need the new version of that gem to loaded.

So removing the Gemfile.lock will let bundle download the correct version of the gems.

If that doesn't work, you might be forcing a version of a gem to load, like `gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"` which has a conflict with another gem, this isn't very common but it can happen. You will have to find the gem with the issue and either remove the version, like so `gem "paperclip"` or find the other gem that has the conflict and get the correct version of that gem. If you use git you can go back through your old Gemfile.lock and see what version of the conflicting gems you have and force that version for those gems. Let's hope the removing your Gemfile.lock works.

Answer (score 1):

Note: before you continue reading this, you need a copy of your `Gemfile.lock` file for this to work, in case you deleted it already!

This might be late now but worth giving this a try for people who did the above and still are faced with the same problem.

My solution was:

1. Use the `Gemfile.lock` file you have (maybe get that from a previous build) and delete the chunk belongs to one of the gems that are dependent on each other.
2. run `bundle install`
3. if the above steps didn't work, repeat (steps 1 and 2) but now with deleting the chunk in the `Gemfile.lock` that belongs to the other gem.
4. if the above didn't work completely, then try (step 1) but without deleting anything. Then update both gems by `bundle update --source gem_name_here`. Now, give the app a run before `bundle install`, if this didn't work, then try to `bundle install` before running the app.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for the answer to this issue, open your Gemfile in a text editor and ensure that you don't:

A) Have the same gem listed twice or

B) Have multiple sources listed for a gem.

In my case, the Gemfile had not been updated since the gem was added to rubygems.org, and so was attempting to pull the gem from both rubygems and the listed git source. Deleting the git source solved the issue.